# Regex extended versions of the same word

Tags: php, regex

How to match using Regex in PHP instances of the same word with repeated letters in it.

I need this to fight extended amounts of "**thanks**" comments.

Typing only "**thanks**" is already prohibited but people obviously figured out typing "**thankss**, **ttthanks**, **thaaaaaaanks**, etc" works.

The Regex should neglect all repeated letters of the key word and return the key word itself.

The Regex shall also not interrupt any prior or later words as "**thanks**" may occur as a genuine part of a full sentence comment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this RegEx:

```
t+h+a+n+k+s+
```

[Live Demo](http://regexr.com/3d1uu)

Comment: This works amazing. Additionally thanks to @noob for poiting out g and i flags.

Answer (score 0):

Well this might not be the ultimate solution to your **specific** problem because people will always find new ways to bypass this, but will catch most of those instances which you are looking for.

**Regex:** `t+[hank]*[xs]+`

**Flags to use:**

- `g` to allow global search i.e more than one matches in string.
- `i` to allow case insensitive match. **As you might want to match upper case too.**

<kbd>**[Regex101 Demo](https://regex101.com/r/eM2jD2/3)**</kbd>